# Bash assign string to variable and print

Tags: string, bash, variable-assignment

This has been driving me mad for the past hour or so. I have four variables, `$A`, `$B`, `$C`, and `$D`. For simplicity's sake, let's assume that the values in each of those variables is their corresponding letter. I have tried to create a variable to hold a string I'd like to print, like so:

```
s="${A} failed. ${B} ${C} ${D}"
echo "$s"
```

I've written a test script exactly like so, and it works perfectly. However, in my actual script, the variables are different.

```
echo $table_name (prints correctly)
echo $source_count (prints correctly)
echo $disk_size (prints correctly)
echo $hive_count (prints correctly)
s="${table_name} failed. ${source_count} ${disk_size} ${hive_count}" (only prints $disk_size and $hive_count)
echo "$s"
```

Can anyone think of a reason that `$s` only seems to store the `$disk_size` and `$hive_count`? Is there any character limit to what can be stored in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$source_count` has a CR at the end. Strip it before using the variable.

Comment: How can I buy you a beer? Thank you for saving my sanity.